# validating a URL with PHP and returning only the host domain name.

Tags: php

I want to validate a domain name and then return the main domain striped down e.g. http://www.example.co.uk/path/ to example.co.uk
I have made a start with help from various sources and can do this with .com, .net, .org, .info & all the .uk’s.

```
$targetUrl = 'http://sub.example.uk/test/';

$host = filter(get_domain($targetUrl));

function filter($domain){
    if($domain){

        $domain_array = explode(".", $domain);
        $domain_count = count($domain_array);
        $domain_last = end($domain_array);
        $domain_first = $domain_array[0];
        $domain_second = $domain_array[1];
        $domain_second_last = array_slice($domain_array, -2, 1);
        $domain_second_last = $domain_second_last[0];
        $domain_third_last = array_slice($domain_array, -3, 1);
        $domain_third_last = $domain_third_last[0];


        // UK Validation
        $uk_second = array('ac', 'co', 'gov', 'judiciary', 'ltd', 'me', 'mod', 'net', 'nhs', 'nic', 'org', 'parliament', 'plc', 'police', 'sch');
        if($domain_last == 'uk'){
            if($domain_count == '2'){
                // if domain.uk
                return $domain;
            }elseif(in_array($domain_second, $uk_second)){
                //if domain.$uk_second.uk
                return $domain;
            }elseif(in_array($domain_second_last, $uk_second)){
                // if subdomain on 2 dd.dd.co.uk rename to dd.co.uk
                $domain = $domain_third_last.'.'.$domain_second_last.'.'.$domain_last;
                return $domain;
            }else{
                // finaly it must be a dsd.sds.uk so lets remove the subdomain 
                $domain = $domain_second_last.'.'.$domain_last;
                return $domain;
            }
        }
        // END .UK
        // SImple Single TLDs 
        $single_tlds = array('com', 'net', 'org', 'info');
        if(in_array($domain_last, $single_tlds)){
            if($domain_count == '2'){
                // simple is it a ddd.com
                return $domain;
            }else{
                $domain = $domain_second_last.'.'.$domain_last;
                return $domain;
            }
        }
    }//if domain
}



function get_domain($domain) {
        $domain = strtolower($domain);   
        if (!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
            $urlParts = parse_url($domain);
            $domain = $urlParts['host'];
            $domain = str_ireplace('www.','',$domain); 
            $original = $domain = strtolower($domain);     
            if (filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) { return $domain; }    
            $arr = array_slice(array_filter(explode('.', $domain, 4), function($value){
                                return $value !== 'www'; }), 0); //rebuild array indexes

            if (count($arr) > 2)    {
                $count = count($arr);
                $_sub = explode('.', $count === 4 ? $arr[3] : $arr[2]);

                if (count($_sub) === 2)  { // two level TLD
                    $removed = array_shift($arr);
                    if ($count === 4) // got a subdomain acting as a domain
                        $removed = array_shift($arr);            

                }
                elseif (count($_sub) === 1){ // one level TLD
                    $removed = array_shift($arr); //remove the subdomain             
                    if (strlen($_sub[0]) === 2 && $count === 3) // TLD domain must be 2 letters
                        array_unshift($arr, $removed);                
                    else{
                        // non country TLD according to IANA
                        $tlds = array(    'aero',    'arpa',    'asia',    'biz',    'cat',    'com',    'coop',    'edu',    'gov',    'info',    'jobs',    'mil',    'mobi',    'museum',    'name',    'net',    'org',    'post',    'pro',    'tel',    'travel',    'xxx',    );             
                        if (count($arr) > 2 && in_array($_sub[0], $tlds) !== false) {//special TLD don't have a country
                            array_shift($arr);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else { // more than 3 levels, something is wrong
                    for ($i = count($_sub); $i > 1; $i--) 
                        $removed = array_shift($arr);

                }
            }
            elseif (count($arr) === 2) {
                $arr0 = array_shift($arr);     
                if (strpos(join('.', $arr), '.') === false
                            && in_array($arr[0], array('localhost','test','invalid')) === false) // not a reserved domain
                {

                    // seems invalid domain, restore it
                    array_unshift($arr, $arr0);
                }
            }     

            return join('.', $arr);

        }

}
```

It’s just not very scalable I’m going to have to go through all the domain suffixes and add them. I’m sure there must be a simpler way? Would someone be so kind to help out? Maybe some way of loading the list from https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

So, for a list of data and the results I would expect to see are:

```
http://subdomain.example.co.uk/path/site.php -> example.co.uk
http://subdomain.example.uk/path/site.php -> example.uk
www.subdomain.example.uk/path/site.php -> example.uk
subdomain.example.uk -> example.uk
http://gobble.gobble.notavalidsuffix -> false
```

Comment: What is the exact question here?

Answer (score 1):

The below will validate a URL by stripping the unnecessary URL parameters etc.. from a domain and then pass this string into `gethostbyname()`. This will then query a DNS server for the given root domain, if successful, you will be presented back with an IP, if not, the same input string will be returned. I have then passed this result into a filter which validates IP strings. If it's successful, it will then return the domain in the format given. Just make sure you are pointing to a DNS provider which will not resolve every DNS lookup...for example, my ISP in the UK automatically resolves every failed DNS lookup with a valid A record which in-turn resolves to web page saying "No Such Webpage". Google DNS works fine so use that if you can.

```
function validDom($url) {

    $newUrl = (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) ? $url : FALSE;

    if ($newUrl === FALSE) {

        return FALSE;
    }

    $urlSplit = explode('/', $newUrl); 

    foreach ($urlSplit as $k=>$v) {

        if(substr_count($v, '.') >= 2) {

            $newUrl = $v;

        } 
    }

    $cleanDomain = substr_replace($newUrl, '', 0, strpos($newUrl, '.')+1);
    $chkDNS = gethostbyname($cleanDomain);

    if (filter_var($chkDNS, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== FALSE) {

        return $cleanDomain;

    }

    return false;

}
```

**Test Domains**

```
$domainArr = [

'https://www.facebook.com',
'https://www.care.org.uk',
'https://www.facebook.co.uk',
'https://www.google.com/dfsdfsdfsd/sdfsdf',
'https://sub.fsdfsdfsdfsdfsd.co.uk/dfsdfsdf', 
'https://www.nhs.uk/dfsdfsdfsdfsd?fgfg=fgfg',
'javascript://comment%0Aalert(1)"hello',

];

        foreach($domainArr as $k=>$v) {

                var_dump(validDom($v));
                echo '<br>';

        }
```

**Output:**

```
string(12) "facebook.com"
string(11) "care.org.uk"
string(14) "facebook.co.uk"
string(10) "google.com"
bool(false)
string(6) "nhs.uk" 
bool(false)
```

*Edit:*

*This function will also get around the issue with malicious code bypassing `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` due to `javascript://comment%0Aalert(1)"hello'` not resolving via DNS which ultimately ends in a fail.*

Comment: Nice one. Lol at the JavaScript hello url. This looks really cool. But still only ASCII characters, which, thankfully, is within the limits of the op's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
function filterUrl ($url) {
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $parts = explode('.', $host);
        $lastParts = array_slice($parts, -3, 3);
        return implode('.', $lastParts);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @shalvah question is not very clear. Must domain name consists some suffix in it? What other requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that validating a url in PHP is a complex task.

You could use the built-in [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions, but as a number of user comments on PHP.net, and even the documentation, point out, they're not very reliable.

For one, they don't support internationalized domain names (URLs containing non-ASCII, e.g. Unicode characters).

> Note that the function will only find ASCII URLs to be valid; **internationalized domain names (containing non-ASCII characters) will fail**.

For another, they pass a lot of false positives. [The documentation states](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php):

> Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol http:// so further validation may be required to determine the URL uses an expected protocol, e.g. ssh:// or mailto:.

They also don't have a list of valid name extensions. This means something like `asdf://asdf.asdf` gets passed by filter_var. I tried it, and it actually was.

`filter_var` could also be a potential XSS vulnerability, because it passes something like `javascript://comment%0Aalert(1)"hello` as valid.

Sorry to be a bearer of bad tidings, but that's the truth. I did spot a number of libraries for validation in PHP which included URLs, but they all still built upon `parse_url` or `filter_var`. I'm also not confident regex could the job.

However, (plug time:) I'm working on a PHP library that should be able to achieve what you want, and I hope to get it done in a couple of days.